# How to use .append on a jQuery .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the data being called rather than replacing it but I'm not sure why .append isn't working.

```
      $('.incoming3').load('t3.html #test3').append;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is a function - you need to use parentheses after it, and supply it with a parameter telling it what to append. Second, you can't just change the way [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) works by chaining `.append()` onto the end of it.

Try this instead:

```
$.get("t3.html", function(data) {
    $('.incoming3').append($(data).filter("#test3"));
});
```

That is, use the [`$.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to retrieve the data, wrap the data in a jQuery object and use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to extract the bit you need, and append that bit to your element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.incoming3').append($('<div>').load('t3.html #test3'));
```

or

```
$.get('t3.html', function(data) {
    $('.incoming3').append($(data).find('#test3'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`load()` method by design replaces the html of the selector. You will need to create your own filtering AJX method.

```
$.get( 't3.html', function(response){
   var contentDesired=$(response).find( '#test3')/* or filter instead of find if no body tag wrapping html*/
   $('.incoming3').append( contentDesired)

})
```

This is virtually identical to one solution I gave you on same situation in your last question for same issue

Comment: Yes, many thanks for the clarification. I think I am starting to get the differences of jQuery ajax.